# How to find, add, remove database entries in MongoDB in a reactJS environment

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am attempting to use MongoDB to store a single text item in a reactJS environment.  Wow, what a complex, unwieldy, set of instructions in the MongoDB documentation...

I think I have created a MongoDB database in the terminal with the use dbName command.  However it does not show up in MongoDB Compass - perhaps it needs to have a record in it before that happens?

I want to replace this text item from time to time and there will be no other items in the db.

I cannot find any straightforward instructions which explain how to find a record, find the number of records (will be 0 or 1), or how to replace a record.

MongoDB is installed locally on the Mac (Catalina).  Mongod is running.  I think that I can create the first entry with the js line:

```
db.page.insertOne({ page: pageName })
```

; but I have not yet tested this.

If anyone knows where I can find the simple instructions I am looking for I would greatly appreciate a link :-)

More info:  The database is installed in System/Volumes/data/db.  There is no security (Unnecessary anyway).  Do I need a connection string?

I am not using Express - there is no html in this application except for the divs exported by each module.  There is no user interaction beyond clicking on the required tile in the navbar.

All the examples I have found all use Express and html aiwth connection strings. :-(

Comment: Check this out; https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/

Comment: So you are planning to make a db query with the help of react ,well not possible without a backend server probably express.

Comment: Lol...  The MongoDB documentation is the worst I have seen...  I will have a look at express - thanks for the tip...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is not too complex - but you would never know that from the MongoDb documentation.  I went back through the Udemy course I did some time ago and found a project which did everything I am trying to do...

MongoDB is easily installed with npm or homebrew.  The database sits in the Apple file system.  The MongoDB driver can be installed and used to create, populate, delete or update data - but installing Mongoose makes it a lot easier.

I don't need Express...